# Using EJS in Express

Tags: node.js, express, routes, ejs

My EJS files are in a `views` folder which is defined in the `app.js` file as follows:

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
```

But currently every time I add a new page I have to specify the route as follows:

```
/* GET login page */
router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});
```

Where `router` is `express.Router()`. Is there a better way? I can't believe I need to add this routing code for every page. What's the best practice for EJS?

Comment: If every page can be rendered with the exact same parameters, why not create static HTML pages and let [`express.static()`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static) handle them?

Comment: They do need to receive data from the server

Comment: If every template needs different parameters, what's the problem of having to set up different routes? You could perhaps fold all routes into one, but you still have to account for the different parameters that should go with each template.